# Excel VBA: Listbox

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

on a separate Excel 2007 VBA question, how do i use the listbox under "Developer" > "Form Control" ?

i would like to display some data from another worksheet (say wsData), however i would like to display the data specific to a user (say wsInterface, cell A1), and NOT use the "format control" > "control" > "input range"

so i will have a form that pops up to prompt the user for a name to be keyed into worksheet wsInterface cell A1, and i would like the data relevant to the user to be displayed in the listbox. Thanks

wsData:

```
name  |   date   | remarks
Mr A     22/2/11   blah blah blah 1.
Mr B     22/2/11   blah blah blah 2.
Mr A     23/2/11   blah blah blah 3.
```

wsInterface:

```
Cell A1: Mr A

ListBox (2 columns)
22/2/11   blah blah blah 1.
23/2/11   blah blah blah 3.
```

here are my codes in one of the macro:

```
Sub CustRemarkListBox_Change()
    Dim lbtarget As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rngSource = Range("Remarks")
```

**Set lbtarget = CustRemarkListBox**

```
    With lbtarget
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "50;200"
        For Each rw In rngSource.Rows
            If rw.Cells(1, 1) = Worksheets("ExistingCustomer").Range("C4") Then
                .AddItem ""
                For i = 1 To .ColumnCount
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, i - 1) = rw.Cells(1, i)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

The one in bold is my problem, it says "Object Required" meaning it did not detect my listbox in my Excel Worksheet that was named "CustRemarkListBox"

Comment: Are you using a Listbox from the Form Controls section?  Those controls don't have a 'change event' or any events for that matter.  Also, those objects aren't part of the MSForms library.  Everything you seem to be doing is for ActiveX controls, so I want to be clear about what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, the user has to enter a name into a cell, and you want the listbox to get populated based on the name entered?

You could use something like the Worksheet_Range event to run some code to populate the listbox when you enter a name it can match.

How familiar are you with VBA? You could use something like the following in the codpage for the relevant sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)  
If Target.Address = "A1" Then  
'put your code here  
End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: i m not sure how do i select the listbox in excel. for example in forms which i m more familiar, i can select listboxes via their names (e.g. form1 lboxData). but i cant seem to select the listbox in the excel itself even if i use its name.

Comment: Then right click on the control in Excel, and select 'Assign Macro'. It will show a Macro dialog, with the default of ListBox1_Change. New will apply this to a new module. If you have renamed it from List Box 1, then it will create the event as YourName_Change().  HTH.  Martin

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for answering but it didnt solve my problem. Basically i edited my post and pasted the codes in. The BOLD section is where the error lies: Excel VBA is unable to detect my listbox named "CustRemarkListBox" which resides in one of my Excel Worksheet, inserted via Developer > Form Control > Listbox.